# Merge/Append a [AnyHashable: Any]() on Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have the follow objects and a would like to merge then.

```
  var prop1 = [AnyHashable: Any]()
  prop1["key1"] = "Phase3"
  prop1["key2"] = "405"

  var prop2 = [AnyHashable: Any]()
  prop2["key3"] = "Phase1"
  prop2["key4"] = "45"
```

I want a final object `prop1+prop2` a `[AnyHashable: Any]()`, what's the best way to do so?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with `prop1+prop2`. Please describe the `type` of the result value and its content.

Comment: The two dictionaries have different values for the *same keys.* So what would the expected result be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
let union = Array(prop2.keys).reduce(prop1) { (dict, key) -> [AnyHashable:Any] in
    var dict = dict
    dict[key] = prop2[key]
    return dict
}
```

### Example

```
var prop1 = [AnyHashable: Any]()
prop1["key1"] = "Phase3"
prop1["key2"] = "405"

var prop2 = [AnyHashable: Any]()
prop2["key3"] = "Phase1"
prop2["key4"] = "45"


let union = Array(prop2.keys).reduce(prop1) { (dict, key) -> [AnyHashable:Any] in
    var dict = dict
    dict[key] = prop2[key]
    return dict
}

dump(union) //
```

### Duplicates

Please note that if the same key is present in both dictionaries, the result will get the value from `prop2` for that specific key.

Example

```
let prop1 : [AnyHashable: Any] = ["key1": "value from prop1"]
let prop2 : [AnyHashable: Any] = ["key1": "value from prop2"]


let union = Array(prop2.keys).reduce(prop1) { (dict, key) -> [AnyHashable:Any] in
    var dict = dict
    dict[key] = prop2[key]
    return dict
}

print(union) // [AnyHashable("key1"): "value from prop2"]
```

Comment: This is gonna be great: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md

Comment: And https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md @Alexander :)